# How to define a set as a subset with the property relative to set i.e. standard deviation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, standard-deviation

So i'm reading a book on applied category theory and while i can understand how to define a subset with a simple property i.e. "all even numbers" i'm curious how you define it based in a more real work scenario. As in if you had the set of people (maybe a "class of students") how would you define a subset that is a set of all people who's age is 1 standard deviation from the mean? or am i thinking about thing wrong?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what "defining a set" means in this context.  For your example, "$S$ is the set of all students whose age is 1 standard deviation from the mean" would be a valid definition of a set.

Comment: It was more of an example. To say you have a set of something and then to define 1 or many subsets of that set that match a more complex property

Comment: My point is that as soon as you have stated the defining property, you have technically "defined a set" in the mathematical sense, so it doesn't really matter how complex the property is.

Comment: Ok i think i understand. I wanted to use LaTeX to write this out but i guess that's not possible. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to specifically define your set in [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation)?

Comment: Yes that's the final result, i've seen them defined as even numbers etc but never anything concreate/complex

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your specific example.  We have a set of students, and we would like to define the subset consisting of all people who's age is within 1 standard deviation from the mean.  Here is how this set might be described symbolically:

> Let $S$ denote a set of students.  For a student $s \in S$, let $\operatorname{age}(s)$ denote the age of that student.  We define the set of ages by
>   $$
> A = \{a \in \Bbb N : \text{there is a student } s \in S \text{ such that} \operatorname{age}(s) = a\}.
> $$
>   Let $\mu,\sigma$ denote the mean and standard deviation of $A$, respectively.  We then define
>   $$
> S = \{s \in S: |\operatorname{age}(s) - \mu| 
> \leq \sigma\}.
> $$

In this context, $S$ would be the set that we were trying to define.

Comment: You're the best, thankyou!

Comment: one question here, should that be `age(s)=a` ?

Comment: @Dale Yes, good catch

Comment: @Dale Also, that definition of $A$ is often abbreviated as
$$
A = \{\operatorname{age}(s) : s \in S\}.
$$